# Competitive Coding - Clearing all levels with minimum cost : Not passing all test cases

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was solving problems on a competitive coding website when I came across this. The problem states that:
In this game there are N levels and M types of available weapons. The levels are numbered from 0 to N-1 and the weapons are numbered from 0 to M-1 . **You can clear these levels in any order.** In each level, some subset of these M weapons is required to clear this level. If in a particular level, you need to buy x new weapons, you will pay x^2 coins for it. Also note that you can carry all the weapons you have currently to the next level . Initially, you have no weapons. Can you find out the minimum coins required such that you can clear all the levels?

**Input Format**
The first line of input contains 2 space separated integers: 
N = the number of levels in the game
M = the number of types of weapons

N lines follows. The ith of these lines contains a binary string of length M. If the jth character of
this string is 1 , it means we need a weapon of type j to clear the ith level.

**Constraints**
1 <= N <=20
1<= M <= 20

**Output Format**
Print a single integer which is the answer to the problem.

**Sample TestCase 1**
Input
1 4
0101
Output
4

**Explanation**
There is only one level in this game. We need 2 types of weapons - 1 and 3. Since, initially Ben
has no weapons he will have to buy these, which will cost him 2^2 = 4 coins.

**Sample TestCase 2**
Input
3 3
111
001
010

Output
3

**Explanation**
There are 3 levels in this game. The 0th level (111) requires all 3 types of weapons. The 1st level (001) requires only weapon of type 2. The 2nd level requires only weapon of type 1. If we clear the levels in the given order(0-1-2), total cost = 3^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 9 coins. If we clear the levels in the order 1-2-0, it will cost = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3 coins which is the optimal way.

**Approach**
I was able to figure out that we can calculate the minimum cost by traversing the Binary Strings in a way that we purchase minimum possible weapons at each level.

One possible way could be traversing the array of binary strings and calculating the cost for each level while the array is already arranged in the correct order. The correct order should be when the Strings are already sorted i.e. 001, 010, 111 as in case of the above test case. Traversing the arrays in this order and summing up the cost for each level gives the correct answer.

Also, the sort method in java works fine to sort these Binary Strings before running a loop on the array to sum up cost for each level.

```
Arrays.sort(weapons);
```

This approach work fine for some of the test cases, however more than half of the test cases are still failing and I can't understand whats wrong with my logic. I am using bitwise operators to calculate the number of weapons needed at each level and returning their square.

Unfortunately, I cannot see the test cases that are failing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also buy a weapon that you do not need for the next level?

Comment: While buying the weapons for a level, you would want to buy only the weapons that are needed for that level, buying other weapons which are  not needed would increase the cost, so why would you want to do that?

Comment: Lets say you have levels 0001 and 1111. If you buy only the weapons you need you will have cost 1*1 + 3*3 =10 but if you buy two weapons for the first level and two for the second you will have 2*2 + 2*2 = 8, which is clearly better.

Comment: So, as you have stated, the optimal way is to order the levels in a way that the smallest number of additional weapons needs to be purchased in any given level. However, this isn't necessarily the sorted order of Strings. Perhaps you should parse into `BitSet` and sort by the number of set bits.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul Agree with you. The right way is to count the number of set bits instead of just regular sorting. However, even after sorting the Strings according to number of set bits, all test cases do not pass.

Comment: Doesn't that belong more on CodeReview or another SE site ?

Comment: I think bit set sorting becomes more complicated, because you're actually looking for the minimum number of *additional* bits set, given all preceding bits. So after passing all levels in which a single weapon needed to be purchased (which would be an unavoidable cost of 2 per level), you may want to then subtract all those bits from the remaining levels before sorting the remainder for the next group of levels. That next group would again be the lowest number of *additional* bits set.

Comment: I doubt that the problem can be reduced to a simple sorting problem.

Comment: I don't see how this can be simplified sorting problem and @SaiBot asks an important question - but the phrasing "weapon you need" suggests that you may not buy additional weapons. BTW: The second test case has two solutions for the given cost (1-2-0 and 2-1-0).

Comment: @JeremyGrand Not really. Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.

Comment: Also, can you return to the same level twice? Like, clear a part of it, then do something else and then return back to it and clear it completely.

Comment: @lexicore so on neither of them ? As much as this question may be interesting, I don't think it belongs in here, at least not in this form. This is way too much a `help me with my homework` (even if this is not homework per se) than a `how to solve a technical issue`

Comment: @JeremyGrand From my POV it's [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as a "software algorithm".

Comment: @JeremyGrand Even considering this a homework, the OP demonstrated a good faith attempt. Also the question can be interpreted as about a problem with an existing implementation.

Comment: @JeremyGrand To sum up, I personaly did not vote to close. I like this question, it shows an interesting problem. And I would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved by dynamic programming.

The state will be the bit mask of weapons we currently own.

The transitions will be to try clearing each of the `n` possible levels in turn from the current state, acquiring the additional weapons we need and paying for them.
In each of the `n` resulting states, we take the minimum cost of the current way to achieve it and all previously observed ways.
When we already have some weapons, some levels will actually require no additional weapons to be bought; such transitions will automatically be disregarded since in such case, we arrive at the same state having paid the same cost.

We start at the state of `m` zeroes, having paid `0`.
The end state is the bitwise OR of all the given levels, and the minimum cost to get there is the answer.

In pseudocode:

```
let mask[1], mask[2], ..., mask[n] be the given bit masks of the n levels
p2m = 2 to the power of m
f[0] = 0
all f[1], f[2], ..., f[p2m-1] = infinity
for state = 0, 1, 2, ..., p2m-1:
    current_cost = f[state]
    current_ones = popcount(state)  // popcount is the number of 1 bits
    for level = 1, 2, ..., n:
        new_state = state | mask[level]  // the operation is bitwise OR
        new_cost = current_cost + square (popcount(new_state) - current_ones)
        f[new_state] = min (f[new_state], new_cost)
mask_total = mask[1] | mask[2] | ... | mask[n]
the answer is f[mask_total]
```

The complexity is `O(2^m * n)` time and `O(2^m)` memory, which should be fine for `m <= 20` and `n <= 20` in most online judges.

Comment: @SaiBot All possible sequences are `n!` in number, and `20! = 2,432,902,008,176,640,000`. On the other hand, `2^20` is only `1,048,576`. The savings due to the use of dynamic programming are this conversion of `n!` into `2^n`: the dynamic programming state drops the _in-what-order_ part, and leaves only the _bought-or-not_ part.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic optimization idea by @Gassa could be extended by using [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)  by estimating min and max of the remaining cost, where

```
minRemaining(s)=bitCount(maxState-s)
maxRemaining(s)=bitCount(maxState-s)^2
```

Start with a priority queue - and base it on cost+minRemaining - with the just the empty state, and then replace a state from this queue that has not reached maxState with at most n new states based the n levels:

Keep track `bound=min(cost(s)+maxRemaining(s))` in queue, 
and initialize all costs with `bitCount(maxState)^2+1`

```
extract state with lowest cost
if state!=maxState
   remove state from queue
   for j in 1..n 
      if (state|level[j]!=state)
        cost(state|level[j])=min(cost(state|level[j]), 
           cost(state)+bitCount(state|level[j]-state)^2
        if cost(state|level[j])+minRemaining(state|level[j])<=bound
           add/replace state|level[j] in queue
else break
```

The idea is to skip dead-ends. So consider an example from a comment

```
11100 cost 9 min 2 max 4
11110 cost 16 min 1 max 1
11111 cost 25 min 0 max 0
00011 cost 4 min 3 max 9
bound 13
remove 00011 and replace with 11111 (skipping 00011 since no change)
11111 cost 13 min 0 max 0
11100 cost 9 min 2 max 4
11110 cost 16 min 1 max 1
remove 11100 and replace with 11110 11111 (skipping 11100 since no change):
11111 cost 13 min 0 max 0
11110 cost 10 min 1 max 1
bound 11
remove 11110 and replace with 11111 (skipping 11110 since no change)
11111 cost 11 min 0 max 0
bound 11
```

Number of operations should be similar to dynamic optimization in the worst case, but in many cases it will be better - and I don't know if the worst case can occur.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this problem is that every time you have to find the minimum count of set bits  corresponding to a binary string which will contain the weapons so far got in the level.

For ex :
we have data as 
4 3 
101-2 bits
010-1 bits
110-2 bits
101-2 bits
now as 010 has min bits we compute cost for it first then update the current pattern (by using bitwise OR) so current pattern is 010
next we find the next min set bits wrt to current pattern
i have used the logic by first using XOR for current pattern and the given number then using AND with the current number(A^B)&A
so the bits become like this after the operation
(101^010)&101->101-2 bit
(110^010)&110->100-1 bit
 now we know the min bit is 110 we pick it and compute the cost ,update the pattern and so on..
This method returns the cost of a string with respect to current pattern

```
private static int computeCost(String currPattern, String costString) {
  int a = currPattern.isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(currPattern, 2);
  int b = Integer.parseInt(costString, 2);
  int cost = 0;
  int c = (a ^ b) & b;
  cost = (int) Math.pow(countSetBits(c), 2);
  return cost;
    }
```

Comment: This is also wrong. Consider levels `11100`, `11110`, `11111`, and also `00011`. The solution will take `00011` first paying 4, after which it would have to pay 9 for the first three bits simultaneously anyway, for a total of 13. Whereas if we start with paying 9 for `11100`, we can proceed with `11110` and then `11111` paying a total of 9 + 1 + 1 = 11.