# Distance algorithm - minimum coins required to clear all the level

Tags: algorithm, combinations, hamming-distance

Thor is playing a game where there are N levels and M types of available weapons. The levels are numbered from 0 to N-1 and the weapons are numbered from 0 to M-1. He can clear these levels in any order. In each level, some subset of these M weapons is required to clear this level. If in a particular level, he needs to buy x new weapons, he will pay x^2 coins for it. Also note that he can carry all the weapons he has currently to the next level. Initially, he has no weapons. Can you find out the minimum coins required such that he can clear all the levels?

**Input Format**

The first line of input contains 2 space separated integers:

N = the number of levels in the game

M = the number of types of weapons

N lines follow. The ith of these lines contains a binary string of length M. If the jth character of this string is 1, it means we need a weapon of type j to clear the ith level.

**Constraints**

1 <= N <= 20

1 <= M <= 20

**Output Format**

Print a single integer which is the answer to the problem.

**Sample TestCase 1**

*Input*

```
1 4 
0101
```

*Output*

```
4
```

*Explanation*

There is only one level in this game. We need 2 types of weapons - 1 and 3. Since, initially, Thor has no weapons he will have to buy these, which will cost him 2^2 = 4 coins.

**Sample TestCase 2**

*Input*

```
3 3 
111
001
010
```

*Output*

```
3
```

*Explanation*

There are 3 levels in this game. The 0th level (111) requires all 3 types of weapons. The 1st level (001) requires only weapon of type 2. The 2nd level requires only weapon of type 1. If we clear the levels in the given order (0-1-2), total cost = 3^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 9 coins. If we clear the levels in the order 1-2-0, it will cost = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3 coins, which is the optimal way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This isn't a free homework service. Please show us what you've tried so far to solve the problem, and why you're stuck. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Ravi Manna - do you have a link to the problem ? I have a solution in mind, would like to test it before posting here.

Comment: @zenwraight - I read this problem on a website and tried solving from there, however, wasn't sure on the approach to be taken. I tried using hamming distance but got stuck with some test cases. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @FeiXiang - I tried using hamming distance algorithm however I am unable to get through all of the test cases, can you help with some clue. When I used hamming distance I was not able to get through this - Consider levels 11100, 11110, 11111, and also 00011. The solution will take 00011 first paying 4, after which it would have to pay 9 for the first three bits simultaneously anyway, for a total of 13. Whereas if we start with paying 9 for 11100, we can proceed with 11110 and then 11111 paying a total of 9 + 1 + 1 = 11

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49772462/9254539. Can't flag though since I already flagged this post as too broad because it's a homework/competitive programming problem dump.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Competitive Coding - Clearing all levels with minimum cost : Not passing all test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772462/competitive-coding-clearing-all-levels-with-minimum-cost-not-passing-all-tes)

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of [Gassa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784291/2034787) is partly in the fact that if a different state can be reached by `or`ing one of the levels' bitstring masks with the current state, we are guaranteed that achieving the current state did not include visiting this level (since otherwise those bits would already be set). This means checking a transition from one state to another by adding a different bitmask, guarantees we are looking at an ordering that did not yet include that mask. So a formulation like Gassa's could work: let `f(st)` represent the cost of acheiving state `st`, then:

```
f(st) = min(
  some known cost of f(st),
  f(prev_st) + (popcount(prev_st | level) - popcount(prev_st))^2
)
for all level and prev_st that or to st
```